# jQuery addEventListener not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I have a script that includes addEventListener and have discovered it isn't supported in < IE9. All the fixes I have seen, do not work when edited according to my script, so looking for some tailored help!

```
    $(document).ready(function(){




var excuses = [

'excuse one',
'excuse two',
'excuse three',
'excuse four',
'excuse five',
'excuse six',
'excuse seven',
'excuse eight',
'excuse nine'

];

var bttn = document.getElementById('refresh');
var excuse = document.getElementById('excuse');
var rando = 0;

var makeExcuse = function(){
  rando = Math.floor(Math.random()*excuses.length);
  excuse.innerHTML = excuses[rando];
};



makeExcuse();

bttn.addEventListener('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  makeExcuse();






});



});
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
if(!bttn.addEventListener) {
    bttn.attachEvent("onclick", makeExcuse);
}
else {
    bttn.addEventListener("click", makeExcuse, false);
}
```

You must do this for IE8 and older because it is not supported in versions older than IE 9. It is documented in this, about halfway down the page.

[Legacy Internet Explorer and Attach Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FEventTarget.addEventListener#Legacy_Internet_Explorer_and_attachEvent)

Comment: Fantastic! I assume I am to replace the code- makeExcuse();

bttn.addEventListener('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  makeExcuse();

Comment: That should work, correct.

Answer (score 0):

Just do it the jQuery  way:

```
 $('#refresh').bind('click', makeExcuse);
```